# Angular directive is too slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular directive and factory to implement a simple countdown timer. The timer does work, but it is rendered on the page too slowly; the timer always gets rendered last. Is there any way I can speed up the process?

HTML

```
<div time date = 'January 1, 2016 12:00:00'></div>
```

DIRECTIVE

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('time', ['timeUtil', '$interval', function(timeUtil, $interval) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { date: '@' },

        link: function(scope, element) {

            var date = new Date(scope.date);

            $interval(function() {
                var diff;
                diff = Math.floor((date.getTime()-new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
                return element.text(timeUtil.dhms(diff));
            }, 1000);
        }
   }
}])
```

FACTORY

```
.factory('timeUtil', [function() {
    return {
      dhms: function(t) {
        var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
        days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
        t -= days * 86400;
        hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
        t -= hours * 3600;
        minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
        t -= minutes * 60;
        seconds = t % 60;
        return [days + 'd', hours + 'h', minutes + 'm', seconds + 's'].join(' ');
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: If that code is too slow, it's probably because something else on your page slows it down. It looks OK as it is. Do you have a Fiddle or example so that we could see the actual slowness?

Comment: appears to work for me [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jc3eLx9r/), it updates the div every second

Comment: It does work, but it shows up late. It is the last element that gets rendered on my page.

Comment: Maybe provide some more information and/or context, because it seems to work great, as an above comment has shown in a fiddle. You should be a little more specific than "it shows up late", are other things running slowly? How long does it take to render? What else do you have on the page/app?

Comment: Does the interval you set a) fire the function then wait a second for the next call or b) wait a second then fire the function... Check it out.